# im trying to figure out why this x86 assembly code to ID palindromes thinks everything is a palindrome

Tags: assembly, x86, palindrome, irvine32

. I've been at this for a few days at this point and despite looking through all other responses to this exact problem on this site i am unable to figure out what im doing wrong. Can anyone provide me with some help? For some reason, when I move the values of each string using [esi] and [edi] into al and dl respectively. When these vals are eventually compared they always set the zero flag, irrespective of whether or not the values are equal

```
BufSize = 80
.data
msg BYTE "Input a string for reversal: ",0
msg1 BYTE "palindrome",0
msg2 BYTE "not palindrome",0
buffer BYTE BufSize DUP(?),0,0
bytesRead DWORD ?
string1 DWORD ?
string2 DWORD ?
   TEMP1 DW 0
   PALMESSAGE DB "  THE PROVIDED STRING IS A PALINDROME $"
   NOTPALMESSAGE DB "  THE PROVIDED STRING IS NOT A PALINDROME $"
.CODE
main proc

; Wait for user input
    mov edx, OFFSET buffer
    mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer
    call ReadString
    mov bytesRead, eax
    mov string1, edx
    mov ecx, bytesread
    mov esi,0

COMPARE:
   MOVZX EAX, buffer[esi]
   push eax
   inc esi
   LOOP COMPARE

    mov ecx,bytesRead
    mov esi,0

    L2: 
    pop eax ; get character
    mov buffer[esi],al  ; store in string
    inc esi
    Loop L2

    mov string2, offset buffer
    mov ecx, bytesread
    mov edx, string2
    call writestring

    mov ecx,bytesRead
    mov esi,0
    mov edi,0
    ;mov eax,0
    ;mov edx,0
    mov esi, string1
    mov edi, string2

    L3:
       mov  al, [esi]
       mov  dl, [edi]
       cmp al,0 ; end of string1?
       jne L4 ; no
       cmp dl,0 ; yes: end of string2?
       jne L4 ; no
       jmp pal ; yes, exit with ZF = 1
   L4: 
       inc esi ; point to next
       inc edi
       cmp al,dl ; characters equal?
       je L3 ; yes: continue loop
       jmp notpal         ; no: exit with flags set

PAL:  
    mov edx, OFFSET msg1
    call WriteString
    call crlf
   JMP FIN   
NOTPAL:   
    mov edx, OFFSET msg2
    call WriteString
    call crlf
FIN:


    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: This looks like Irvine32.  And you're using `push eax` so this can't possible be 64-bit code.  I fixed your tags to use x86 instead of x86-64.

Comment: gotta love those lightning fast quarantine response times! thanks

Comment: turned my comment into an answer since I realized it really was sufficient to be an answer, and this question is enough of a [mcve] that it doesn't need to get closed or deleted so might as well get officially answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you use the same buffer for the reversed string that you used for the initial input.  string1 holds the same pointer as string2.  So of course they compare equal; at least that's a good sign that the rest of your code might be working.

> When these vals are eventually compared they always set the zero flag, irrespective of whether or not the values are equal

`cmp al,dl` will definitely not set ZF if the values in `al` and dl` differ.  If you think that's happening, you're using your debugger wrong.  It should let you examine registers / memory while you single-step your code.  Ideally even highlighting which registers were changed by the last instruction.

---

Your clunky inefficient algorithm looks like it would work if you used a separate buffer, if there aren't any other bugs.

Inefficient because it loops once to expand the string to 4 bytes per character on the stack, then loops over it again to store in a buffer, then loops over it *again* to check for equality.

The standard algorithm is to start with pointers to the head/tail and loop until they meet in the middle, O(n) time, O(1) extra space, and best case O(1) runtime if the first/last bytes differ.  (Reversing first costs O(n) time and extra space before doing even one compare).  On x86 you can even check 4 or 16 bytes at a time with `bswap` or `pshufb` to byte-reverse an integer or XMM register, reducing the constant factor even more.  (But making short strings a special case.)

---

BTW, your compare loop could also be optimized:

Note that if `al != 0`, you can catch the `dl == 0` end-of-string case as part of `al != dl`.  A `strcmp` implementation only needs to check the strings against each other and *one* of the strings for the terminating zero.